# 'RequestBodyTooLarge' when trying to upload Blob to Azure Storage via node createBlockBlobFromStream()

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage

When I'm trying to upload 100MB file to Azure blob storage, using `createBlockBlobFromStream()` from azure node sdk, I receive this error:

```
error: { code: 'RequestBodyTooLarge',
  message: 'The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit.
  maxlimit: '67108864' }
```

Any ideas? Max blob size seems to be 200GB, or 50.000 blocks. I checked constants, block size is set on 4MB which is maximal. SDK bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

The following is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179451):

> If you attempt to upload a block blob that is larger than 64 MB, or a
>   page blob larger than 1 TB, the service returns status code 413
>   (Request Entity Too Large). The Blob service also returns additional
>   information about the error in the response, including the maximum
>   blob size permitted in bytes.

You may want to check createBlockBlobFromStream() to verify that it uses blocks of less than 4MB for uploads of files larger than 64MB. You can use Fiddler, for example, to verify the actual REST operation and that should show pretty quickly what operation is attempted by createBlockBlobFromStream().

Comment: From a quick glance at the code, it looks like `createBlockBlobFromStream` makes no attempt to break a large stream into blocks.